# Limit of a composite function that is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

Below is a link to the graph that I'm working with.

[Graph of function f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esr6T.png)

From this graph, based on my understanding:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} f(x)$$

The limit **does not exist**. This is because as $x$ approaches $2$, $f(x)$ is approaching multiple values (specifically $-2$ and $2$).

The next question is where I'm finding this confusing, which is to compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -3} f(f(x))$$

As $x$ approaches $-3$ (but $x \neq -3$), $f(x)$ is close to $2$. I know that for composition of limits, we can only "sub in" the output of the inner function, which is $2$ in this case, as the input of the outer function when at least 1 of following conditions are satisfied:

Consider $g\circ f(x)$

1. $f(x) \neq 2$ for $x$ on an interval centered at $-3$, except maybe at $-3$.
2. $g$ continuous at $2$.

Based on what I see on the graph, $f(x)=2$ on the interval around $x=-3$, so the first condition fails. Also, $g$, which I think is the outer $f$ function, is not continuous at $x=2$. So both conditions have failed. Based on this, we would not be able to "sub in" the inner function into the outer function legitimately.

So I tried to work backwards from the answer, which is $-1$. The only thing I could come up with was that as $x$ approaches $-3$, $f(x)=2$. It is not close to $2$, it is exactly $2$. Since it is exactly $2$ and not approaching $2$, we can just sub in the output $2$ into the outer function $f$, and $f(2)=-1$. I'm a bit skeptical that this kind of answer would be correct, but I've run out of ideas. Has my reasoning made sense so far? Perhaps I may be missing out on a key idea?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Although I'm not 100% sure, I think the answer has to do with the idea that $\lim_{x\rightarrow -3} f(f(x))$ isn't actually a composition of limits at all. The prerequisites for composition of limits are:

1. $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$
2. $\lim_{y\to L}g(y)=M$

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ means that when $x$ is close to $a$ (but $x\neq a$), **$f(x)$ is close to $L$**. In our case of $x\to -3$, when $x$ is close to $-3$ (but $x\neq -3$), $f(x)=2$ and **is not close to 2**. So when we use the output of (1) (which is not a limit anymore by the definition) as the input for (2), there is no need to obey at least one of the two conditions because this is not a composition of limits. We can simply compute and get the final answer of $-1$.

Comment: $f$ is only discontinuous at $x=2$. Since $f$ is continuous on a neighborhood of $x=-3$, we have $\lim\limits_{x\to -3}f(f(x))=f\left(\lim\limits_{x\to-3}f(x)\right)=f(f(-3))$.

Comment: @CSquared But shouldn't $g$ have a requirement to be continuous at $x=2$? Otherwise $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(f(x))=f\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)\right)=f(f(0))=f(2)=-1$, which is incorrect because the answer when $x\to0$ is $-2$. I thought the reason the answer was $-2$, in simple terms, was because as $x\to0$, $f(x)\to2^-$, therefore $f(f(x))=-2$. Also, in this case, I believe condition #1 is satisfied so the composition of limits would be allowed.

Comment: i retract my earlier statement. good point. i remember doing these in AP Calc a couple years ago. the best thing to do in these situations if you want a quick answer is to look at left and right sided limits, graphically. do you have to justify your answers? and if so, just with words or an entire proof?

Comment: An entire proof is probably not necessary because the question says "compute the following limits". So just putting the final answer down is probably enough, but I'm more interested in the reasoning behind the answers.

Comment: ok. i’ll try and get back to you with an answer

Comment: Can you observe that the function $f(f(x)) $ takes a constant value $-1$ in a deleted neighborhood of $-3$? This means that the desired limit is $-1$. The problem would have been more interesting if the values of $f$ in neighborhood of $-3$ were either less than $2$ or more than $2$ of a mix of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention you are interested in the reasoning behind the answers, lets go into that first. To be more general, let $A,B,C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be non-empty and lets say $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ are two functions. Given some $a\in A$, we can say that $$\lim_{x\to a}g(f(a))=g\left(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\right)$$ provided that $g$ is continuous at $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$.

In your case, we had two points of interest: $x=-3$ and $x=0$. Both of these cases fail to satisfy the above conditions, so we have to resort to another method, that being left and right sided limits.

In the case where $x=-3$, we can approach $x$ from the left and the right; approaching from the left, graphically, tells us that $\lim\limits_{x\to -3^-}f(f(x))=-1$ and approaching from the right tells us that $\lim\limits_{x\to -3^+}f(f(x))=-1$. This means $\lim\limits_{x\to -3}f(f(x))=-1$.

Now, in the case where $x=0$, approaching from the left of zero yields $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}f(f(x))=-2$ and approaching from the right similarly yields $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(f(x))=-2$.

Since you don't need to be completely rigorous in your justification, to compute, for example, the left sided limits, simply move your finger near the left of $-3$ and approximate the out put of $f$ where you finger is. For example, lets say your finger is near $x'=-3.5$. Then $f(-3.5)=2$ and $f(f(-3.5))=f(2)=-1$. From the right, lets say your finger is near $x'=-2.5$. Then $f(f(-2.5))=f(2)=-1$. Since these limits agree, then you can be sure your answer is  $-1$. This is not a very precise answer, but the reasoning behind it is left and right sided limits if you're more interested. Trying to provide epsilon-delta proofs would be a good way to strengthen your understanding of why this works.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at it from side limits provides a lot insight, and it makes sense. The only point that I'm unsure about is if $f(f(-3))=f(2)=-1$ would be a legal use of composition of limits since it seems like the two conditions in my question have failed when $x\to-3$. Indeed, once I start working on more epsilon-delta proofs practice problems I think my understanding on this whole topic will be strengthened overall.

Comment: @JeffD the composition of limits $\lim\limits_{x\to-3} f(f(x))$ being equal to $-1$ without the justification of left and right sided limits is illegal in this case, and the reason is because the second condition in your question is not satisfied. i’m not sure why you would want to impose the first condition. that seems extremely restrictive and unnecessary.

Comment: the reason is because of the explanation in this video (I'll place the link at the very bottom of the comment). The issue is roughly mentioned by the instructor at 5:33 to 7:23. To quickly summarize it here, the theorem for composition of limits fails. The two conditions in my opening question leads to two theorems that "fix" the theorem of composition of limits. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1WYANJ7IPc&list=PLlwePzQY_wW8P_I8BFgm0-upywEwTKd8_&index=18

Comment: Upvoted because your answer was the most helpful. Thanks!